# word 2010, How to view the entire merge field when attempting to add switches

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

I'm having a senior moment. I have some other's word document set up for mail merge from excel. I am trying to add a date switch but when I press Ctrl F9, I cannot see the whole field to add my switch. How can I see the whole field? 
Can someone please refresh my memory.

[image]

Notice how in the column, I cant see anything. Besides moving the columns, I cant figure out what to do. I cant remember. Thanks

Comment: Anybody know? Any hints to try? I ran out of ideas.

Comment: I usually select the field and copy it to a point outside the table (but then of course it may behave differently), fix it, then copy back. In some cases you may need to ensure that there is nothing else in the cell, but there are various ways you could do that.

Comment: Thank you. I have been doing that but I was hoping there was an easier way. Sometimes the copy of the Bracketed switches dont behave properly. I appreciate the input though. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, there are various things that could go wrong in a copy - e.g. references to other cells in the table would not work, or might be interpreted as bookmarks, and so on.